# kendo ui treelist - set cell template

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I would like to set a span in every cell of `Kendo TreeList`, I am getting this by default in `Kendo Grid` but I am not able to set this in `Kendo TreeList`

Kendo Grid :

```
    <td role="gridcell" title="Control Box">
          <span ng-bind="dataItem.partdesc" class="ng-binding">Control Box</span>    
    </td>
```

Kendo TreeList :

```
    <td role="gridcell" title="Control Box"></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you two workaround, first you can use **column template** (but you have to modify all column if you want every cell to have span like the one you described) like e.g

```
$("#treelist").kendoTreeList({
  columns: [ {
    field: "name",
    template: "<span class='Test'>#:name#</span> "
  }],
  dataSource: [ { name: "Jane Doe" }, { name: "John Doe" } ]
});
```

> [DEMO](http://dojo.telerik.com/unomE)

Or you can insert the span on **databound** like e.g

```
$("#treeList").kendoTreeList({
      columns: [
        { field: "Name" },
        { field: "Position" }
      ],
      dataSource: [
        { id: 1, Name: "Daryl Sweeney", Position: "CEO", parentId: null },
        { id: 2, Name: "Guy Wooten", Position: "Chief Technical Officer", parentId: 1 }
      ],
      dataBound: function(e) {
        e.sender.table.find("td[role='gridcell']").append("<span class='test'>Test</span>");
      }
 });
```

> [DEMO](http://dojo.telerik.com/EwuRo)